# How to use git for Data Science/ ML projects

Tags: git, github, repository, data-science, branch

Three of my fellow students and I take part at a hackathon and have 10 days. We obtained a data set and have to predict a variable. However, I'm wondering what's the best way to use git for such projects. We have two main directories *model* and *data*. Being a data science project, a lot of data preprocessing is required. We're using jupyter notebooks both for the data cleaning and for the model itself. How can we efficiently clean the data working as a team in terms of  git-repo-structure? I am not sure how to manage the repo properly. Should everyone have his own branch? Or is it more convenient if everyone works on the master branch and pushes the updated data set and jupyter notebooks? Because there is no "running system" that is usually in the master branch. We're experimenting a lot with the data and the model. Does it even make sense to use git? Sorry for that chaotic question though

Comment: Few useful links : [Is there a Git for data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/748/is-there-a-git-for-data), [Git (and Github) for Data](https://blog.okfn.org/2013/07/02/git-and-github-for-data/).

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, data science and software development are fundamentally at odds. Usually the needs of data science win since those are directly pertinent to business need, and the result (if you aren't careful) is messy, confusing code that nobody can follow (including you).

"Data science" requires you to ask lots of questions, which means you iterate as fast as you possibly can. Much of the code you write won't give you the answer you want, so you end up with a bunch of chaotic, one-off scripts. Sometimes its hard to know if a script you write is even worth committing.

"Software development" requires documentation, planning, testing, refactoring to keep the code readable, etc in addition to actually writing the code. This requires you to slow down, which "data science" doesn't want you to do. Obviously this is hackathon so the "rules" are more relaxed, but they exist to make it easier to develop code and work in teams, which you are trying to do.

Short answer: yes you should use git.

Without knowing more about your project, here are some more specific tips:

- **organize the git repo up front**: Have separate directories for `data` (for the dataset), `model` (and maybe subdirectories for each model you are trying), `cleaning` (for cleaning scripts, see below), and maybe `plots` or `output` and keep them divided as cleanly as you can. If one model has a ton of messy scripts because you are experimenting, at least that noise is contained. This also makes dividing work much easier, one directory = one task.
- **subset the data**: If the dataset is massive, use a small slice (like 10%) and do all your initial development with that and scale up later. "Massive" is "anything big enough to make you wait a long time for things to run."
- **automate the data cleaning as much as possible**: Write a cleaning script, then call the cleaning script from the model script. If the dataset is massive and takes an hour for the script to clean, save the output to the repo and commit it, then call the cleaned dataset from the model script. This way you don't need to diff a giant CSV file; all the information is in the cleaning script.
- **don't use jupyter notebooks (unless you really want/need them)**: I realize there are tools to help make git and jupyter get along, but those are still several orders of magnitude more complicated than a raw script. This is in addition to [other reasons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jiPeIFXb6U) why notebooks in general make writing organized code harder.
- **save the model when necessary**: some packages will optionally spit out a model that you can save/commit and load in the future without training it again. I would only do this if the model takes a long time to run (which in my opinion is more than a few minutes). Otherwise it's just more clutter in the repo.
- **use virtual environments**: you didn't mention what language you are using, but in the case of Python (one example) use `pyenv` and `virtualenv` (or your favorite since there are several ways to do this). In my experience many "data science" packages can be fickle when changing versions (especially when you start getting into GPU computation and other fun stuff), so having the team stick to one version for the runtime and associated packages can save lots of headache.
- **don't forget to commit**: Seems obvious, but when you are trying answer questions and most of the code you write will fail, it helps to know why. It's tempting to think that the project will "stay small enough that you'll remember" ...but it won't.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer! I implemented many of your suggestions to our workflow and am pretty sure they helped organise our work.

Answer (score 1):

Concepts in [MLOPS](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/03/overview-mlops.html) might be useful for your case as well; somethings like Data Version Control ([DVC](https://dvc.org/)) for data versioning and [MLFlow](https://mlflow.org/) for managing "the ML lifecycle, including experimentation, reproducibility, deployment, and a central model registry".